# Chat web application jquery scrollTop issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, scrolltop

I have developed a Chat web application. Facing problem regarding jquery scrollTop. see the below snippet.

what i want... on page load event all chat conversations scrolls to bottom and shows the last message. when top arrow button is clicked it will scroll slowly and vice versa.

what i am getting... on page load all the conversations are scrolled to bottom. Then when the top or bottom what ever button is pressed it goes all way to the top (its the main prb). After that it works fine.

Plz give me a proper advice how to overcome it. Thanks in advance.

```js
var scrolled = 0;
var scrolledspreed = 100;

var container = jQuery('#sc-chat-listg');
    var row = jQuery('div.sc-single-gl', container).last();
    if (row.length) {
     var r_position = row.position();
     var c_scrollTop = container.scrollTop() + r_position.top;

     jQuery('#sc-chat-listg').animate({scrollTop: c_scrollTop}, 1000);
    }


 
 $("#sg-top").on("click" ,function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  
  scrolled=scrolled-scrolledspreed;
  
  $("#sc-chat-listg").animate({
    scrollTop:  scrolled
  });
  
  $('.sc-inbtn').append(scrolled);
  
 });
 
 $("#sg-bottom").on("click" ,function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  
  scrolled=scrolled+scrolledspreed;

  $("#sc-chat-listg").animate({
   scrollTop:  scrolled
  });
  
  $('.sc-inbtn').append(scrolled);

 });
```

```css
ul.sc-chat-list {
 list-style: none outside none;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 overflow: scroll;
    height: 200px;
}

ul.sc-chat-list > li {
 background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #f0f0f0;
 display: block;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
 margin-left: 5px;
 margin-right: 5px;
}

div.sc-single-chat {
 border: 1px solid #c7d1c7;
 padding: 11px 14px;
 overflow: hidden;
}

div.sc-single-gl {
 cursor: pointer;
}

div.sc-avatar {
 float: left;
 width: 65px;
}

div.sc-avatar > img {
  margin-top: 7px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

div.sc-cm {
  overflow: hidden;
}

span.sc-usname {
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 25px;
}

span.sc-id {
  font-size: 11px;
  border: 1px solid #c1c1c1;
  padding: 0 3px;
}

span.sc-time {
 float: right;
 font-size: 11px;
}

div.sc-cm > p {
 color: #666666;
 font-size: 15px;
 margin: 0;
}

a.sg-arrow-top {
 position: absolute;
 right: 25px;
 top: 0;
 border: 0px !important;
}

a.sg-arrow-top > img {
  height: auto;
  width: 40px;
}

a.sg-arrow-bottom {
  bottom: 17px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 25px;
  border: 0px !important;
}

a.sg-arrow-bottom > img {
  height: auto;
  width: 40px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-12 sc-global">
   <div class="sc-chat-container">
    <ul class="sc-chat-list sc-clg" id="sc-chat-listg">   
   <li>
    <div class="sc-single-chat sc-single-gl" id="row-1470422400" data-relun="66169008000" data-reluid="1">
     <div class="sc-avatar"><img width="50" height="50" class="avatar avatar-50 photo" src="http://0.gravatar.com/avatar/889e8e0ec0a2cc8a2fa827ced481eb56?s=50&amp;d=http%3A%2F%2F0.gravatar.com%2Favatar%2Fad516503a11cd5ca435acc9bb6523536%3Fs%3D50&amp;r=G" alt=""></div>
     <div class="sc-cm">
      <div style="overflow: hidden;"><span class="sc-usname">S.k.joy</span> <span class="sc-id">ID - 45</span><span class="sc-time">August 5, 2016 6:40 pm</span></div>
      <p>Hi</p>
     </div>
    </div>
   </li>
   
     
   <li>
    <div class="sc-single-chat sc-single-gl" id="row-1470479340" data-relun="67642049640" data-reluid="1">
     <div class="sc-avatar"><img width="50" height="50" class="avatar avatar-50 photo" src="http://0.gravatar.com/avatar/889e8e0ec0a2cc8a2fa827ced481eb56?s=50&amp;d=http%3A%2F%2F0.gravatar.com%2Favatar%2Fad516503a11cd5ca435acc9bb6523536%3Fs%3D50&amp;r=G" alt=""></div>
     <div class="sc-cm">
      <div style="overflow: hidden;"><span class="sc-usname">S.k.joy</span> <span class="sc-id">ID - 46</span><span class="sc-time">August 6, 2016 10:29 am</span></div>
      <p>Hello</p>
     </div>
    </div>
   </li>
   
     
   <li>
    <div class="sc-single-chat sc-single-gl" id="row-1470479400" data-relun="69112531800" data-reluid="1">
     <div class="sc-avatar"><img width="50" height="50" class="avatar avatar-50 photo" src="http://0.gravatar.com/avatar/889e8e0ec0a2cc8a2fa827ced481eb56?s=50&amp;d=http%3A%2F%2F0.gravatar.com%2Favatar%2Fad516503a11cd5ca435acc9bb6523536%3Fs%3D50&amp;r=G" alt=""></div>
     <div class="sc-cm">
      <div style="overflow: hidden;"><span class="sc-usname">S.k.joy</span> <span class="sc-id">ID - 47</span><span class="sc-time">August 6, 2016 10:30 am</span></div>
      <p>Working perfect</p>
     </div>
    </div>
   </li>
   
     
   <li>
    <div class="sc-single-chat sc-single-gl" id="row-1470490500" data-relun="77935996500" data-reluid="1">
     <div class="sc-avatar"><img width="50" height="50" class="avatar avatar-50 photo" src="http://0.gravatar.com/avatar/889e8e0ec0a2cc8a2fa827ced481eb56?s=50&amp;d=http%3A%2F%2F0.gravatar.com%2Favatar%2Fad516503a11cd5ca435acc9bb6523536%3Fs%3D50&amp;r=G" alt=""></div>
     <div class="sc-cm">
      <div style="overflow: hidden;"><span class="sc-usname">S.k.joy</span> <span class="sc-id">ID - 53</span><span class="sc-time">August 6, 2016 1:35 pm</span></div>
      <p>Lokks</p>
     </div>
    </div>
   </li>
   
     
   <li>
    <div class="sc-single-chat sc-single-gl" id="row-1470490680" data-relun="79406496720" data-reluid="1">
     <div class="sc-avatar"><img width="50" height="50" class="avatar avatar-50 photo" src="http://0.gravatar.com/avatar/889e8e0ec0a2cc8a2fa827ced481eb56?s=50&amp;d=http%3A%2F%2F0.gravatar.com%2Favatar%2Fad516503a11cd5ca435acc9bb6523536%3Fs%3D50&amp;r=G" alt=""></div>
     <div class="sc-cm">
      <div style="overflow: hidden;"><span class="sc-usname">S.k.joy</span> <span class="sc-id">ID - 54</span><span class="sc-time">August 6, 2016 1:38 pm</span></div>
      <p>See</p>
     </div>
    </div>
   </li>
   
     
   <li>
    <div class="sc-single-chat sc-single-gl" id="row-1470491160" data-relun="80877013800" data-reluid="1">
     <div class="sc-avatar"><img width="50" height="50" class="avatar avatar-50 photo" src="http://0.gravatar.com/avatar/889e8e0ec0a2cc8a2fa827ced481eb56?s=50&amp;d=http%3A%2F%2F0.gravatar.com%2Favatar%2Fad516503a11cd5ca435acc9bb6523536%3Fs%3D50&amp;r=G" alt=""></div>
     <div class="sc-cm">
      <div style="overflow: hidden;"><span class="sc-usname">S.k.joy</span> <span class="sc-id">ID - 55</span><span class="sc-time">August 6, 2016 1:46 pm</span></div>
      <p>Heloo</p>
     </div>
    </div>
   </li>
   
     
   <li>
    <div class="sc-single-chat sc-single-gl" id="row-1470491220" data-relun="82347508320" data-reluid="1">
     <div class="sc-avatar"><img width="50" height="50" class="avatar avatar-50 photo" src="http://0.gravatar.com/avatar/889e8e0ec0a2cc8a2fa827ced481eb56?s=50&amp;d=http%3A%2F%2F0.gravatar.com%2Favatar%2Fad516503a11cd5ca435acc9bb6523536%3Fs%3D50&amp;r=G" alt=""></div>
     <div class="sc-cm">
      <div style="overflow: hidden;"><span class="sc-usname">S.k.joy</span> <span class="sc-id">ID - 56</span><span class="sc-time">August 6, 2016 1:47 pm</span></div>
      <p>World</p>
     </div>
    </div>
   </li>
   
     
   <li>
    <div class="sc-single-chat sc-single-gl" id="row-1470491880" data-relun="83818037160" data-reluid="1">
     <div class="sc-avatar"><img width="50" height="50" class="avatar avatar-50 photo" src="http://0.gravatar.com/avatar/889e8e0ec0a2cc8a2fa827ced481eb56?s=50&amp;d=http%3A%2F%2F0.gravatar.com%2Favatar%2Fad516503a11cd5ca435acc9bb6523536%3Fs%3D50&amp;r=G" alt=""></div>
     <div class="sc-cm">
      <div style="overflow: hidden;"><span class="sc-usname">S.k.joy</span> <span class="sc-id">ID - 57</span><span class="sc-time">August 6, 2016 1:58 pm</span></div>
      <p>hai</p>
     </div>
    </div>
   </li>
   
     
   <li>
    <div class="sc-single-chat sc-single-gl" id="row-1470492600" data-relun="85288570800" data-reluid="1">
     <div class="sc-avatar"><img width="50" height="50" class="avatar avatar-50 photo" src="http://0.gravatar.com/avatar/889e8e0ec0a2cc8a2fa827ced481eb56?s=50&amp;d=http%3A%2F%2F0.gravatar.com%2Favatar%2Fad516503a11cd5ca435acc9bb6523536%3Fs%3D50&amp;r=G" alt=""></div>
     <div class="sc-cm">
      <div style="overflow: hidden;"><span class="sc-usname">S.k.joy</span> <span class="sc-id">ID - 58</span><span class="sc-time">August 6, 2016 2:10 pm</span></div>
      <p>hello</p>
     </div>
    </div>
   </li>
   
     
   <li>
    <div class="sc-single-chat sc-single-gl" id="row-1470677880" data-relun="86769994920" data-reluid="1">
     <div class="sc-avatar"><img width="50" height="50" class="avatar avatar-50 photo" src="http://0.gravatar.com/avatar/889e8e0ec0a2cc8a2fa827ced481eb56?s=50&amp;d=http%3A%2F%2F0.gravatar.com%2Favatar%2Fad516503a11cd5ca435acc9bb6523536%3Fs%3D50&amp;r=G" alt=""></div>
     <div class="sc-cm">
      <div style="overflow: hidden;"><span class="sc-usname">S.k.joy</span> <span class="sc-id">ID - 59</span><span class="sc-time">August 8, 2016 5:38 pm</span></div>
      <p>hi</p>
     </div>
    </div>
   </li>
   
     
   <li>
    <div class="sc-single-chat sc-single-gl" id="row-1470680040" data-relun="88240802400" data-reluid="1">
     <div class="sc-avatar"><img width="50" height="50" class="avatar avatar-50 photo" src="http://0.gravatar.com/avatar/889e8e0ec0a2cc8a2fa827ced481eb56?s=50&amp;d=http%3A%2F%2F0.gravatar.com%2Favatar%2Fad516503a11cd5ca435acc9bb6523536%3Fs%3D50&amp;r=G" alt=""></div>
     <div class="sc-cm">
      <div style="overflow: hidden;"><span class="sc-usname">S.k.joy</span> <span class="sc-id">ID - 60</span><span class="sc-time">August 8, 2016 6:14 pm</span></div>
      <p>Heloo</p>
     </div>
    </div>
   </li>
   
     
   <li>
    <div class="sc-single-chat sc-single-gl" id="row-1470680100" data-relun="89711486100" data-reluid="1">
     <div class="sc-avatar"><img width="50" height="50" class="avatar avatar-50 photo" src="http://0.gravatar.com/avatar/889e8e0ec0a2cc8a2fa827ced481eb56?s=50&amp;d=http%3A%2F%2F0.gravatar.com%2Favatar%2Fad516503a11cd5ca435acc9bb6523536%3Fs%3D50&amp;r=G" alt=""></div>
     <div class="sc-cm">
      <div style="overflow: hidden;"><span class="sc-usname">S.k.joy</span> <span class="sc-id">ID - 61</span><span class="sc-time">August 8, 2016 6:15 pm</span></div>
      <p>mewaws</p>
     </div>
    </div>
   </li>
   
     
   <li>
    <div class="sc-single-chat sc-single-gl" id="row-1470680280" data-relun="91182177360" data-reluid="1">
     <div class="sc-avatar"><img width="50" height="50" class="avatar avatar-50 photo" src="http://0.gravatar.com/avatar/889e8e0ec0a2cc8a2fa827ced481eb56?s=50&amp;d=http%3A%2F%2F0.gravatar.com%2Favatar%2Fad516503a11cd5ca435acc9bb6523536%3Fs%3D50&amp;r=G" alt=""></div>
     <div class="sc-cm">
      <div style="overflow: hidden;"><span class="sc-usname">S.k.joy</span> <span class="sc-id">ID - 62</span><span class="sc-time">August 8, 2016 6:18 pm</span></div>
      <p>Hello</p>
     </div>
    </div>
   </li>
   
     
   <li>
    <div class="sc-single-chat sc-single-gl" id="row-1470680340" data-relun="92652861420" data-reluid="1">
     <div class="sc-avatar"><img width="50" height="50" class="avatar avatar-50 photo" src="http://0.gravatar.com/avatar/889e8e0ec0a2cc8a2fa827ced481eb56?s=50&amp;d=http%3A%2F%2F0.gravatar.com%2Favatar%2Fad516503a11cd5ca435acc9bb6523536%3Fs%3D50&amp;r=G" alt=""></div>
     <div class="sc-cm">
      <div style="overflow: hidden;"><span class="sc-usname">S.k.joy</span> <span class="sc-id">ID - 63</span><span class="sc-time">August 8, 2016 6:19 pm</span></div>
      <p>World</p>
     </div>
    </div>
   </li>
   
   <li>
    <div class="sc-single-chat sc-single-gl" id="row-1470680040" data-relun="88240802400" data-reluid="1">
     <div class="sc-avatar"><img width="50" height="50" class="avatar avatar-50 photo" src="http://0.gravatar.com/avatar/889e8e0ec0a2cc8a2fa827ced481eb56?s=50&amp;d=http%3A%2F%2F0.gravatar.com%2Favatar%2Fad516503a11cd5ca435acc9bb6523536%3Fs%3D50&amp;r=G" alt=""></div>
     <div class="sc-cm">
      <div style="overflow: hidden;"><span class="sc-usname">S.k.joy</span> <span class="sc-id">ID - 60</span><span class="sc-time">August 8, 2016 6:14 pm</span></div>
      <p>Heloo</p>
     </div>
    </div>
   </li>
   
     
   <li>
    <div class="sc-single-chat sc-single-gl" id="row-1470680100" data-relun="89711486100" data-reluid="1">
     <div class="sc-avatar"><img width="50" height="50" class="avatar avatar-50 photo" src="http://0.gravatar.com/avatar/889e8e0ec0a2cc8a2fa827ced481eb56?s=50&amp;d=http%3A%2F%2F0.gravatar.com%2Favatar%2Fad516503a11cd5ca435acc9bb6523536%3Fs%3D50&amp;r=G" alt=""></div>
     <div class="sc-cm">
      <div style="overflow: hidden;"><span class="sc-usname">S.k.joy</span> <span class="sc-id">ID - 61</span><span class="sc-time">August 8, 2016 6:15 pm</span></div>
      <p>mewaws</p>
     </div>
    </div>
   </li>
   
     
   <li>
    <div class="sc-single-chat sc-single-gl" id="row-1470680280" data-relun="91182177360" data-reluid="1">
     <div class="sc-avatar"><img width="50" height="50" class="avatar avatar-50 photo" src="http://0.gravatar.com/avatar/889e8e0ec0a2cc8a2fa827ced481eb56?s=50&amp;d=http%3A%2F%2F0.gravatar.com%2Favatar%2Fad516503a11cd5ca435acc9bb6523536%3Fs%3D50&amp;r=G" alt=""></div>
     <div class="sc-cm">
      <div style="overflow: hidden;"><span class="sc-usname">S.k.joy</span> <span class="sc-id">ID - 62</span><span class="sc-time">August 8, 2016 6:18 pm</span></div>
      <p>Hello</p>
     </div>
    </div>
   </li>
   
     
   <li>
    <div class="sc-single-chat sc-single-gl" id="row-1470680340" data-relun="92652861420" data-reluid="1">
     <div class="sc-avatar"><img width="50" height="50" class="avatar avatar-50 photo" src="http://0.gravatar.com/avatar/889e8e0ec0a2cc8a2fa827ced481eb56?s=50&amp;d=http%3A%2F%2F0.gravatar.com%2Favatar%2Fad516503a11cd5ca435acc9bb6523536%3Fs%3D50&amp;r=G" alt=""></div>
     <div class="sc-cm">
      <div style="overflow: hidden;"><span class="sc-usname">S.k.joy</span> <span class="sc-id">ID - 63</span><span class="sc-time">August 8, 2016 6:19 pm</span></div>
      <p>World</p>
     </div>
    </div>
   </li>
   
  </ul>
    <a class="sg-arrow-top" href="" id="sg-top"><img alt="Top" src="http://skjoy.info/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/top_arrow.png"></a>
    <a class="sg-arrow-bottom" href="" id="sg-bottom"><img alt="Bottom" src="http://skjoy.info/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/bottom_arrow.png"></a>
   </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make **c_scrollTop** global,
So once the page is loaded **c_scrollTop** will be containing the actual scroll position.

After that,

```
scrolled = c_scrollTop;
$("#sg-top").on("click",function(){.....});
$("#sg-bottom").on("click",function(){.....});
```

Answer (score 1):

set:

```
scrolled = c_scrollTop;
```

just after this line:

```
var c_scrollTop = container.scrollTop() + r_position.top;
```

```js
var scrolled = 0;
var scrolledspreed = 100;

var container = jQuery('#sc-chat-listg');
    var row = jQuery('div.sc-single-gl', container).last();
    if (row.length) {
                  
     var r_position = row.position();
     var c_scrollTop = container.scrollTop() + r_position.top;
                    scrolled = c_scrollTop;

     jQuery('#sc-chat-listg').animate({scrollTop: c_scrollTop}, 1000);
    }


 
 $("#sg-top").on("click" ,function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  
  scrolled=scrolled-scrolledspreed;
  
  $("#sc-chat-listg").animate({
    scrollTop:  scrolled
  });
  
  $('.sc-inbtn').append(scrolled);
  
 });
 
 $("#sg-bottom").on("click" ,function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  
  scrolled=scrolled+scrolledspreed;

  $("#sc-chat-listg").animate({
   scrollTop:  scrolled
  });
  
  $('.sc-inbtn').append(scrolled);

 });
```

```css
ul.sc-chat-list {
 list-style: none outside none;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 overflow: scroll;
    height: 200px;
}

ul.sc-chat-list > li {
 background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #f0f0f0;
 display: block;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
 margin-left: 5px;
 margin-right: 5px;
}

div.sc-single-chat {
 border: 1px solid #c7d1c7;
 padding: 11px 14px;
 overflow: hidden;
}

div.sc-single-gl {
 cursor: pointer;
}

div.sc-avatar {
 float: left;
 width: 65px;
}

div.sc-avatar > img {
  margin-top: 7px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

div.sc-cm {
  overflow: hidden;
}

span.sc-usname {
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 25px;
}

span.sc-id {
  font-size: 11px;
  border: 1px solid #c1c1c1;
  padding: 0 3px;
}

span.sc-time {
 float: right;
 font-size: 11px;
}

div.sc-cm > p {
 color: #666666;
 font-size: 15px;
 margin: 0;
}

a.sg-arrow-top {
 position: absolute;
 right: 25px;
 top: 0;
 border: 0px !important;
}

a.sg-arrow-top > img {
  height: auto;
  width: 40px;
}

a.sg-arrow-bottom {
  bottom: 17px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 25px;
  border: 0px !important;
}

a.sg-arrow-bottom > img {
  height: auto;
  width: 40px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-12 sc-global">
   <div class="sc-chat-container">
    <ul class="sc-chat-list sc-clg" id="sc-chat-listg">   
   <li>
    <div class="sc-single-chat sc-single-gl" id="row-1470422400" data-relun="66169008000" data-reluid="1">
     <div class="sc-avatar"><img width="50" height="50" class="avatar avatar-50 photo" src="http://0.gravatar.com/avatar/889e8e0ec0a2cc8a2fa827ced481eb56?s=50&amp;d=http%3A%2F%2F0.gravatar.com%2Favatar%2Fad516503a11cd5ca435acc9bb6523536%3Fs%3D50&amp;r=G" alt=""></div>
     <div class="sc-cm">
      <div style="overflow: hidden;"><span class="sc-usname">S.k.joy</span> <span class="sc-id">ID - 45</span><span class="sc-time">August 5, 2016 6:40 pm</span></div>
      <p>Hi</p>
     </div>
    </div>
   </li>
   
     
   <li>
    <div class="sc-single-chat sc-single-gl" id="row-1470479340" data-relun="67642049640" data-reluid="1">
     <div class="sc-avatar"><img width="50" height="50" class="avatar avatar-50 photo" src="http://0.gravatar.com/avatar/889e8e0ec0a2cc8a2fa827ced481eb56?s=50&amp;d=http%3A%2F%2F0.gravatar.com%2Favatar%2Fad516503a11cd5ca435acc9bb6523536%3Fs%3D50&amp;r=G" alt=""></div>
     <div class="sc-cm">
      <div style="overflow: hidden;"><span class="sc-usname">S.k.joy</span> <span class="sc-id">ID - 46</span><span class="sc-time">August 6, 2016 10:29 am</span></div>
      <p>Hello</p>
     </div>
    </div>
   </li>
   
     
   <li>
    <div class="sc-single-chat sc-single-gl" id="row-1470479400" data-relun="69112531800" data-reluid="1">
     <div class="sc-avatar"><img width="50" height="50" class="avatar avatar-50 photo" src="http://0.gravatar.com/avatar/889e8e0ec0a2cc8a2fa827ced481eb56?s=50&amp;d=http%3A%2F%2F0.gravatar.com%2Favatar%2Fad516503a11cd5ca435acc9bb6523536%3Fs%3D50&amp;r=G" alt=""></div>
     <div class="sc-cm">
      <div style="overflow: hidden;"><span class="sc-usname">S.k.joy</span> <span class="sc-id">ID - 47</span><span class="sc-time">August 6, 2016 10:30 am</span></div>
      <p>Working perfect</p>
     </div>
    </div>
   </li>
   
     
   <li>
    <div class="sc-single-chat sc-single-gl" id="row-1470490500" data-relun="77935996500" data-reluid="1">
     <div class="sc-avatar"><img width="50" height="50" class="avatar avatar-50 photo" src="http://0.gravatar.com/avatar/889e8e0ec0a2cc8a2fa827ced481eb56?s=50&amp;d=http%3A%2F%2F0.gravatar.com%2Favatar%2Fad516503a11cd5ca435acc9bb6523536%3Fs%3D50&amp;r=G" alt=""></div>
     <div class="sc-cm">
      <div style="overflow: hidden;"><span class="sc-usname">S.k.joy</span> <span class="sc-id">ID - 53</span><span class="sc-time">August 6, 2016 1:35 pm</span></div>
      <p>Lokks</p>
     </div>
    </div>
   </li>
   
     
   <li>
    <div class="sc-single-chat sc-single-gl" id="row-1470490680" data-relun="79406496720" data-reluid="1">
     <div class="sc-avatar"><img width="50" height="50" class="avatar avatar-50 photo" src="http://0.gravatar.com/avatar/889e8e0ec0a2cc8a2fa827ced481eb56?s=50&amp;d=http%3A%2F%2F0.gravatar.com%2Favatar%2Fad516503a11cd5ca435acc9bb6523536%3Fs%3D50&amp;r=G" alt=""></div>
     <div class="sc-cm">
      <div style="overflow: hidden;"><span class="sc-usname">S.k.joy</span> <span class="sc-id">ID - 54</span><span class="sc-time">August 6, 2016 1:38 pm</span></div>
      <p>See</p>
     </div>
    </div>
   </li>
   
     
   <li>
    <div class="sc-single-chat sc-single-gl" id="row-1470491160" data-relun="80877013800" data-reluid="1">
     <div class="sc-avatar"><img width="50" height="50" class="avatar avatar-50 photo" src="http://0.gravatar.com/avatar/889e8e0ec0a2cc8a2fa827ced481eb56?s=50&amp;d=http%3A%2F%2F0.gravatar.com%2Favatar%2Fad516503a11cd5ca435acc9bb6523536%3Fs%3D50&amp;r=G" alt=""></div>
     <div class="sc-cm">
      <div style="overflow: hidden;"><span class="sc-usname">S.k.joy</span> <span class="sc-id">ID - 55</span><span class="sc-time">August 6, 2016 1:46 pm</span></div>
      <p>Heloo</p>
     </div>
    </div>
   </li>
   
     
   <li>
    <div class="sc-single-chat sc-single-gl" id="row-1470491220" data-relun="82347508320" data-reluid="1">
     <div class="sc-avatar"><img width="50" height="50" class="avatar avatar-50 photo" src="http://0.gravatar.com/avatar/889e8e0ec0a2cc8a2fa827ced481eb56?s=50&amp;d=http%3A%2F%2F0.gravatar.com%2Favatar%2Fad516503a11cd5ca435acc9bb6523536%3Fs%3D50&amp;r=G" alt=""></div>
     <div class="sc-cm">
      <div style="overflow: hidden;"><span class="sc-usname">S.k.joy</span> <span class="sc-id">ID - 56</span><span class="sc-time">August 6, 2016 1:47 pm</span></div>
      <p>World</p>
     </div>
    </div>
   </li>
   
     
   <li>
    <div class="sc-single-chat sc-single-gl" id="row-1470491880" data-relun="83818037160" data-reluid="1">
     <div class="sc-avatar"><img width="50" height="50" class="avatar avatar-50 photo" src="http://0.gravatar.com/avatar/889e8e0ec0a2cc8a2fa827ced481eb56?s=50&amp;d=http%3A%2F%2F0.gravatar.com%2Favatar%2Fad516503a11cd5ca435acc9bb6523536%3Fs%3D50&amp;r=G" alt=""></div>
     <div class="sc-cm">
      <div style="overflow: hidden;"><span class="sc-usname">S.k.joy</span> <span class="sc-id">ID - 57</span><span class="sc-time">August 6, 2016 1:58 pm</span></div>
      <p>hai</p>
     </div>
    </div>
   </li>
   
     
   <li>
    <div class="sc-single-chat sc-single-gl" id="row-1470492600" data-relun="85288570800" data-reluid="1">
     <div class="sc-avatar"><img width="50" height="50" class="avatar avatar-50 photo" src="http://0.gravatar.com/avatar/889e8e0ec0a2cc8a2fa827ced481eb56?s=50&amp;d=http%3A%2F%2F0.gravatar.com%2Favatar%2Fad516503a11cd5ca435acc9bb6523536%3Fs%3D50&amp;r=G" alt=""></div>
     <div class="sc-cm">
      <div style="overflow: hidden;"><span class="sc-usname">S.k.joy</span> <span class="sc-id">ID - 58</span><span class="sc-time">August 6, 2016 2:10 pm</span></div>
      <p>hello</p>
     </div>
    </div>
   </li>
   
     
   <li>
    <div class="sc-single-chat sc-single-gl" id="row-1470677880" data-relun="86769994920" data-reluid="1">
     <div class="sc-avatar"><img width="50" height="50" class="avatar avatar-50 photo" src="http://0.gravatar.com/avatar/889e8e0ec0a2cc8a2fa827ced481eb56?s=50&amp;d=http%3A%2F%2F0.gravatar.com%2Favatar%2Fad516503a11cd5ca435acc9bb6523536%3Fs%3D50&amp;r=G" alt=""></div>
     <div class="sc-cm">
      <div style="overflow: hidden;"><span class="sc-usname">S.k.joy</span> <span class="sc-id">ID - 59</span><span class="sc-time">August 8, 2016 5:38 pm</span></div>
      <p>hi</p>
     </div>
    </div>
   </li>
   
     
   <li>
    <div class="sc-single-chat sc-single-gl" id="row-1470680040" data-relun="88240802400" data-reluid="1">
     <div class="sc-avatar"><img width="50" height="50" class="avatar avatar-50 photo" src="http://0.gravatar.com/avatar/889e8e0ec0a2cc8a2fa827ced481eb56?s=50&amp;d=http%3A%2F%2F0.gravatar.com%2Favatar%2Fad516503a11cd5ca435acc9bb6523536%3Fs%3D50&amp;r=G" alt=""></div>
     <div class="sc-cm">
      <div style="overflow: hidden;"><span class="sc-usname">S.k.joy</span> <span class="sc-id">ID - 60</span><span class="sc-time">August 8, 2016 6:14 pm</span></div>
      <p>Heloo</p>
     </div>
    </div>
   </li>
   
     
   <li>
    <div class="sc-single-chat sc-single-gl" id="row-1470680100" data-relun="89711486100" data-reluid="1">
     <div class="sc-avatar"><img width="50" height="50" class="avatar avatar-50 photo" src="http://0.gravatar.com/avatar/889e8e0ec0a2cc8a2fa827ced481eb56?s=50&amp;d=http%3A%2F%2F0.gravatar.com%2Favatar%2Fad516503a11cd5ca435acc9bb6523536%3Fs%3D50&amp;r=G" alt=""></div>
     <div class="sc-cm">
      <div style="overflow: hidden;"><span class="sc-usname">S.k.joy</span> <span class="sc-id">ID - 61</span><span class="sc-time">August 8, 2016 6:15 pm</span></div>
      <p>mewaws</p>
     </div>
    </div>
   </li>
   
     
   <li>
    <div class="sc-single-chat sc-single-gl" id="row-1470680280" data-relun="91182177360" data-reluid="1">
     <div class="sc-avatar"><img width="50" height="50" class="avatar avatar-50 photo" src="http://0.gravatar.com/avatar/889e8e0ec0a2cc8a2fa827ced481eb56?s=50&amp;d=http%3A%2F%2F0.gravatar.com%2Favatar%2Fad516503a11cd5ca435acc9bb6523536%3Fs%3D50&amp;r=G" alt=""></div>
     <div class="sc-cm">
      <div style="overflow: hidden;"><span class="sc-usname">S.k.joy</span> <span class="sc-id">ID - 62</span><span class="sc-time">August 8, 2016 6:18 pm</span></div>
      <p>Hello</p>
     </div>
    </div>
   </li>
   
     
   <li>
    <div class="sc-single-chat sc-single-gl" id="row-1470680340" data-relun="92652861420" data-reluid="1">
     <div class="sc-avatar"><img width="50" height="50" class="avatar avatar-50 photo" src="http://0.gravatar.com/avatar/889e8e0ec0a2cc8a2fa827ced481eb56?s=50&amp;d=http%3A%2F%2F0.gravatar.com%2Favatar%2Fad516503a11cd5ca435acc9bb6523536%3Fs%3D50&amp;r=G" alt=""></div>
     <div class="sc-cm">
      <div style="overflow: hidden;"><span class="sc-usname">S.k.joy</span> <span class="sc-id">ID - 63</span><span class="sc-time">August 8, 2016 6:19 pm</span></div>
      <p>World</p>
     </div>
    </div>
   </li>
   
   <li>
    <div class="sc-single-chat sc-single-gl" id="row-1470680040" data-relun="88240802400" data-reluid="1">
     <div class="sc-avatar"><img width="50" height="50" class="avatar avatar-50 photo" src="http://0.gravatar.com/avatar/889e8e0ec0a2cc8a2fa827ced481eb56?s=50&amp;d=http%3A%2F%2F0.gravatar.com%2Favatar%2Fad516503a11cd5ca435acc9bb6523536%3Fs%3D50&amp;r=G" alt=""></div>
     <div class="sc-cm">
      <div style="overflow: hidden;"><span class="sc-usname">S.k.joy</span> <span class="sc-id">ID - 60</span><span class="sc-time">August 8, 2016 6:14 pm</span></div>
      <p>Heloo</p>
     </div>
    </div>
   </li>
   
     
   <li>
    <div class="sc-single-chat sc-single-gl" id="row-1470680100" data-relun="89711486100" data-reluid="1">
     <div class="sc-avatar"><img width="50" height="50" class="avatar avatar-50 photo" src="http://0.gravatar.com/avatar/889e8e0ec0a2cc8a2fa827ced481eb56?s=50&amp;d=http%3A%2F%2F0.gravatar.com%2Favatar%2Fad516503a11cd5ca435acc9bb6523536%3Fs%3D50&amp;r=G" alt=""></div>
     <div class="sc-cm">
      <div style="overflow: hidden;"><span class="sc-usname">S.k.joy</span> <span class="sc-id">ID - 61</span><span class="sc-time">August 8, 2016 6:15 pm</span></div>
      <p>mewaws</p>
     </div>
    </div>
   </li>
   
     
   <li>
    <div class="sc-single-chat sc-single-gl" id="row-1470680280" data-relun="91182177360" data-reluid="1">
     <div class="sc-avatar"><img width="50" height="50" class="avatar avatar-50 photo" src="http://0.gravatar.com/avatar/889e8e0ec0a2cc8a2fa827ced481eb56?s=50&amp;d=http%3A%2F%2F0.gravatar.com%2Favatar%2Fad516503a11cd5ca435acc9bb6523536%3Fs%3D50&amp;r=G" alt=""></div>
     <div class="sc-cm">
      <div style="overflow: hidden;"><span class="sc-usname">S.k.joy</span> <span class="sc-id">ID - 62</span><span class="sc-time">August 8, 2016 6:18 pm</span></div>
      <p>Hello</p>
     </div>
    </div>
   </li>
   
     
   <li>
    <div class="sc-single-chat sc-single-gl" id="row-1470680340" data-relun="92652861420" data-reluid="1">
     <div class="sc-avatar"><img width="50" height="50" class="avatar avatar-50 photo" src="http://0.gravatar.com/avatar/889e8e0ec0a2cc8a2fa827ced481eb56?s=50&amp;d=http%3A%2F%2F0.gravatar.com%2Favatar%2Fad516503a11cd5ca435acc9bb6523536%3Fs%3D50&amp;r=G" alt=""></div>
     <div class="sc-cm">
      <div style="overflow: hidden;"><span class="sc-usname">S.k.joy</span> <span class="sc-id">ID - 63</span><span class="sc-time">August 8, 2016 6:19 pm</span></div>
      <p>World</p>
     </div>
    </div>
   </li>
   
  </ul>
    <a class="sg-arrow-top" href="" id="sg-top"><img alt="Top" src="http://skjoy.info/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/top_arrow.png"></a>
    <a class="sg-arrow-bottom" href="" id="sg-bottom"><img alt="Bottom" src="http://skjoy.info/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/bottom_arrow.png"></a>
   </div>
  </div>
```